# Parsing a URL from a list into a subprocess call

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, subprocess, phantomjs, yslow

The issue is getting call to recognize the o.geturl() command in the call command.

```
from subprocess import call
import time
from urlparse import urlparse

def ListOfTests():
    myFile = open("testUrlToImport.txt", "r")
    myLines = list(myFile)
    myFile.close()

    for urls in myLines:
        urlsAsAString = str(urls)
        o =urlparse(urlsAsAString)

        call(["phantomjs", "yslow.js", "--info", "basic", "--format", "plain", "o.geturl()"])
```

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention - im using nosetests to use this function. $ nosetests -vs UrlPer.py:ListOfTests    The output I see FAIL to load undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove quotes from the `o.geturl()`. This should work:

```
call(["phantomjs", "yslow.js", "--info", "basic", "--format", "plain", o.geturl()])
```